# Proper Layout for Components i.e Navbar & ImageCurosel in Main layout of nextjs project

Tags: reactjs, layout, next.js14

i have created two components now how can i create a proper layout for the components on their exact place in my web project?

i have created two react components i.e Navbar.js & ImageCurosel.js now i want a proper layout for  these components so these component dont overlap or have exact place where they should be placed ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.